# Is there a way to make a hidden call from an iOS app through the telprompt URL scheme?

Tags: ios, swift, hidden, tel

I can make a phone call with this code:

```
if let url = URL(string: "telprompt://\(number)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Now I want to make a phone call with hidden phone number, so I would add `#31#` but then `url` is not, and the `canOpenURL` function is not even called.

```
if let url = URL(string: "telprompt://#31#\(number)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

`tel://` scheme responds the same, and I don't want to go in the system settings and change it there, as it would hide my number on every call I make.

Any idea?

Xcode 11.5 - macOS Catalina - Swift 5

Comment: Not possible in ios. What is exactly mean by hidden call. when you try to call IOS prompt alert to user for permission.

Comment: I mean my phone number should not be displayed to the person I'm calling.

Comment: Not possible. Call with be placed through sim only. So phone number will be visible.

Comment: ```%23``` instead of ```#``` did the trick. Depending on your location, provider, landline or not, the code may change. Here is a list: https://kipkis.com/Call_Private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried url-encoding the `#` ?

```
"telprompt://%2331%23\(number)"
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thx